# Lebesgue integrability of disjoint sum of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Consider a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$.
Let $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets, and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence of integrable functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n=0$ outside $E_n$. Let $f:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$. (No convergence issue here because $E_n$ are disjoint.) **I want to show that** $f$ is integrable if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Vert f_n\Vert<\infty$, where
$\Vert f_n\Vert:=\int |f_n|$.
How can I do that? I'm just a beginner in real analysis, so an easier explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the helpful hints from @geetha290krm, I wrote down a solution which may be easier to comprehend for beginners like myself:

Being a pointwise limit of measurable functions, $f$ is measurable.
Hence, to show that $f$ is integrable, it suffices to show that $|f|$ is integrable.

$|f|$ is measurable, and since $E_n$ are disjoint,
$|f|=\sum_n|f_n|$.

Let $g_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n|f_n|$.
Then $\{g_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of nonnegative integrable functions such that $g_n\to |f|$. Note that
$$\int g_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\int|f_n|=\sum_{i=1}^n\Vert f_n\Vert.$$
Hence, $\sup\int g_n<\infty$.
By the monotone convergence theorem, it follows that $|f|$ is integrable.

Answer (score 3):

$\int |f| \leq \int \sum |f_n|=\sum \int |f_n|=\sum \|f_n\|$ where the interchange of sum and integral is justified by Tonelli's Theorem.

Measurability of $f$ follows from the fact that the partial sums of the series are measurable and point-wise limit of measurable functions is measurtable.

Comment: We want to show the integrability of $f$, and how can you use $\int|f|$ in the proof? Also, I would prefer not using high-end theorems like Tonelli's.

Comment: @ashpool Integral of a non-negative measurable function is always defined. It may be $\infty$ but if is is finite you say that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Tonelli's Theorem can be avoided if you can use Fatou's Lemma or Monotone Convergece Theorem. The question involves interchange of a  limit and an integral and you have to use one of these theorems. @ashpool